# What is the code to permit a user to have only three attempts to log on?

Tags: .net, vb.net, security

I have two combo boxes and one text box that verify subject code, user name and password respectively. I want the user to have only three attempts after which a message is displayed and the form closed.
The code below is supposed to allow the user to have only three attempts to log on but it rather gives the user countless number of attempts. What is wrong with it?

```
    Dim frm As New MarksEntryFrm
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim ctr As Integer = 1
    flag = False
    If ctr < 3 Then
        'ctr = ctr + 1
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select a.Form,a.AcademicYear,b.SubjectID,b.UserID,b.Password,c.Term from StudentDetails.Programmes a, StudentDetails.Subjects b,RegistrationDetails.Registration c where b.SubjectID='" & cboSubjCode.SelectedItem & "'and b.UserID='" & cboUserName.SelectedItem & "' and b.Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", cn)
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ctr = ctr + 1
        If dr1.Read Then
            frm.Show()
            ctr = 0
            'Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Subject Code,User Name or Password. Please try again.", "Wrong data entered", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Aborting")
        Close()

    End If
    dr1.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code doesn't work because `ctr` is a local variable, and thus will not keep its value until the next execution of that method. You need to make it a member field. And of course initializing to 1 and testing with `ctr<3` gives only two attempts, not three.

---

But your code doesn't make any sense from a security point of view.

1. It's client code. And client code can't enforce security. An attacker can simply remove the 3 try restriction.
2. The client has direct database access, i.e. it can simply read(and probably modify) all data, including the passwords from it. In short the client and thus a malicious user owns your database.
3. You have a SQL injection vulnerability since you don't use parametrized statements or encode your user entered parameters.
   This allows a master password that looks something like `' or 1 --`
4. You store plain text passwords. You should use an appropriate password hashing scheme such as PBKDF2 or bcrypt.

1 and 2 are not a problem if this application is only running on a machine you have full control over and the user can only use the pre-installed application and not access the computer in any other way.

Comment: Unexperienced programmers that implement "security" (or the lack of it) is our doom. At least this one came and asked for help...

Comment: The code now works for me having made ctr a member variable,but I now want the user authentication form closed and the MarksEntry form opened as soon as user credentials are verified.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'right' or automatic way to implement a thing like this. You just have to do something that gives you the behavior you want.

In any case you will need to keep track of log in attempts per session. What this means is that you need to have a variable that is kept until the user goes away or is reset after some time or he is successful in logging in. How to do this depends completely on you application and it's context. If this is on the client you have some choices:

The more secure:

- Make a server application that accesses the database and also keeps track of login attempts/username and resets these attempts after some time

The less secure (what you have now):

- Keep it as a client side program that accesses the db directly, and store the login attempts either as a global variable in the application (will be reset when application is restarted) or somehow stored on file (will be reset when your program decides it should be reset, like after some time etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that

```
table:USERS

id(Int)     UserName(VarChar)    Password(VarChar)     Attempts(Int) Attempts_Date(Date)
  1                qayyum             43534rt4              0           11/12/12
```

1. Now when a user try to login and fails increment Attempts and check
   date.
2. If current date not matched the Attempts_Date then update the
   date and reset Attempts to 0 and start increment for fail attempts
   for that date.

   So now you can set maximum number of fail attempts
   for a user for a single day.